# Is there any function in Perl that shifts the array element without removing them?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array, say `@array1 = qw(abc def ghi jkl)`.

Now, I want to use this array in a way that elements are shifted 1 by 1, but that shifting takes place virtually, and not in the array.

Like, "`shift`" will shift the elements and remove them from the array. But, I don't want those elements to be removed.

**Short Code Snippet:**

```
while (my $rName = shift @array1) { 
    my $bName = shift @array1 ; 
    ## Do something now with the value 
}
##And now, I want that I can use @array1 again with the original elements residing
```

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a C-style `for` loop and increment by two. `$#foo` is the index of the last element.

```perl
my @foo = 0 .. 5;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#foo; $i += 2){
    my $r_name = $foo[$i];
    my $b_name = $foo[$i+1];
}
```

If you wanted fancier-looking code, you could use [`natatime` from List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#natatime-EXPR,-LIST) on CPAN, which gives you an iterator that you can use in a `while` loop.

```perl
use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';

my @foo = 0 .. 5;
my $it = natatime 2, @foo;
while ( my ($r_name, $b_name) = $it->() ) {
    print "$r_name $b_name\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The c style for loop will work for me.

Answer (score 4):

In [Perl 5.36](https://metacpan.org/release/RENEEB/perl-5.35.9/view/pod/perl5355delta.pod#iterating-over-multiple-values-at-a-time) you'll be able to do this:

```
for my ($rName, $bName) (@array1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`pairs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#pairs) from the core `List::Util` module:

> A convenient shortcut to operating on even-sized lists of pairs, this function returns a list of `ARRAY` references, each containing two items from the given list.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::Util qw/pairs/;

my @array1 = qw/a 1 b 2 c 3/;
for my $pair (pairs @array1) {
    my ($rName, $bName) = @$pair;
    say "$rName => $bName";
}
say "@array1";
```

Comment: I imagine it's faster just making a copy of the array.

Answer (score 2):

```perl
# Require Perl 5.36
for my ( $rName, $bName ) ( @array1 ) {
   ...
}
```

```perl
my @array2 = @array1;
while ( @array2 ) {
   my $rName = shift @array2;
   my $bName = shift @array2; 
   ...
}
```

```perl
for my $i ( 0 .. $#array1/2 ) {
   my $rName = $array1[ $i * 2 + 0 ];
   my $bName = $array1[ $i * 2 + 1 ];
   ...
}
```

```perl
for ( my $i = 0; $i < @array1; ) {
   my $rName = $array1[ $i++ ];
   my $bName = $array1[ $i++ ];
   ...
}
```

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairs );

for ( pairs @array1 ) {
   my ( $rName, $bName ) = @$_;
   ...
}
```

I tried to organize them from fastest to slowest, but I didn't actually benchmark anything.

Three of the solutions were previously mentioned, but noone mentioned what I think is the fastest solution that doesn't require 5.36 (which hasn't been released yet).

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, how do you calculated their fastness/slowness? I mean, how do you come to know that which method is fastest, and which is comparitively slow? Is there any method to find so?

Comment: Like I said, I didn't do any measurements. It's based on how fast I think they are. The higher ones in the list have fewer Perl operations and create fewer variables.

Comment: @PPP You can use the Benchmark module to check speed differences. But I would say that unless your data load is huge, that is premature optimization. I would use the method that is simplest.

Comment: Absolutely. I do think the solution I added is quote simple, though. It's extremely clear what it's doing at a glance.